# stop undetected_chromedriver to redownload driver patch

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

how to **stop undetected_chromedriver redownloading** driver by running each time?

i've tried set executable_path=driver_path but it didn't stop that

```
def instanciate_driver(attach=False):
    options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    option.headless = True
    binary_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
    browser = uc.Chrome(executable_path=binary_path,
                        options=options, version_main=96)
```

i'll appreciate any help

Answer (score 2):

I think you should pass `driver_executable_path`, not `executable_path`. See the source code [here](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/blob/b2e804e977c9cf3dd9c845474752cac142a72508/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py#L106).

Comment: Also good to remember to give your chromedriver the correct execution permission in case you are running on linux by typing the command: `sudo chmod +x chromedriver` on the terminal.